# Customize Breeze template in laravel

Tags: laravel

I installed [Breeze](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits) in Laravel 8. I found `<x-guest-layout>`, `<x-auth-card>` & `<x-label>` in `register.blade.php` file. These are new to me. I read several docs. But I didn't get any clear conception about this `<x-`.

How can I customize Registration Page ?

Comment: `x-` is often used as a "this is a component, not a built-in HTML tag". It doesn't infer any additional functionality. (The idea comes from its use to denote non-standard HTTP headers, IIRC. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers)

Answer (score 4):

These are blade components and they using the `x-[component name]` naming convention.

Laravel breeze publishes all of its code, including components, so you will find them in your resources folder.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#components